# How to make mysql insert data automatically

Tags: mysql, database

recently I've been introduced into the database world so I am initiating with MySQL, but the problem comes when I am requested to create a database for an art event where adults and children have different entrance costs but like I'm not working with other applications, I have to do everything with SQL instructions so as this language has not -if- instructions I would like you to guide me how to do to assign automatically the cost of an entrance when I register an adult or a child inside a column called "entrance cost"

I have thinking to create an entity called "rate" where I place the maximum age with lower cost (for children) and otherwise assign the cost for adults, but I don't know how to make to compare this data when I register an entrance and assign the cost to the user variable "entrance"

I'm really confused with this exercise so I hope you can get it and help me with that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless you are going to sit there and type in a SQL command for every person that signs up, you will be working with **some** other language. It might not be a language that has native MySQL constructs or a high-level of database abstraction. But it must be something. PHP? Perl? Python? C?

Comment: 'so as this language has not -if- instructions' - that's not the case please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html. The stored program in this case would be a trigger https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/triggers.html and yes creating a table containing rates would be a good way to go. I know that's a lot of stuff to take in for a beginner but please have a go and come back if you get stuck. You should add your table definitions as text to the question together with the trigger code you come up with.

Comment: Definitely, those are features I have to try very soon while going in the learning path.
Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to create one master table to configure rates. and eventually, when you add user entrance data, you can map this with rates from master table.

Let's say we have RateMaster Table(RateId, MinAge, MaxAge, Rate).
You add multiple rate records here with MinAge, MaxAge.

UserEntrance Data will have age mentioned for user and you can refer their rates from RateMaster table.

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: Sure, it was helpful.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, you need to work with another language. You can't do a dinamic application using only SQL.

I'd recommend you to use Spring Boot (http://spring.io/projects/spring-boot) with Java or Kotlin. It's a very straightforward framework that will help you a lot, even if you're a starter.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!